# Alternative Way To Initialize Multiple TextViews

Tags: android, textview, initialization

I want to initialize multiple TextViews (already in a layout file) without having to do it in separate lines (i.e. a loop?). From what I've seen online, I'm aware you can't but just need some confirmation.

```
TextView t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.t1);
TextView t2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.t2);
....
TextView t10 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.t10);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**create programmatically**

```
 for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
     textView = new TextView(ActivityName.this);
     textView.setId(i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i=0; i< 10; i++) {
    int resID = getResources().getIdentifier("t" + (i+1), "id", getPackageName());
    TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(resID));
    ....
   } 
}
```

Comment: Pretty sure this should work (have done something similar before). What issue are you seeing? Can you debug in to code and check if `t` is being set as expected?

Comment: I debugged it and resID is null

Comment: can you try with `getContext().getPackageName()` as last parameter to `getidentifier`

Comment: @D.Jones "resID is null" `resID` is an Integer, it can never be null. There is no reason why this shouldn't work, [it will be slow though.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) John, I'd store `t` in an `ArrayList<TextView>` and change the range of your loop since `"t" + (i+1)` made me chuckle. Why not `int i = 1; i <= 10; i++` with `"t" + i`?

Comment: @Sam the focus of the code was the use of `getIdentifier`....wasn't really on loop logic as wasn't clear (or really relevant to issue at hand) how range/control variables would be managed in actual code.

Comment: @D.Jones did you have any success getting this working?

Comment: @JohnO'Reilly I didn't unfortunately. I stuck to initializing this just by doing it line by line. When looping to find the resource, int resID didn't have anything inside it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no faster way to do this with the basic tools.

However you might find the [Butter Knife](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife) annotation library of interest.

Comment: Sometimes you give everyone upvotes and makes it your own answer look inferior, which it isn't.